# Nifi on kubernetes with nginx ingress getting CORS error

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, ingress-controller

I am trying to deploy Nifi on k8s as deployment and using ingress to expose URL to the public.

Offloaded TLS certs at ingress and trying to terminate at Nginx level.

Getting CORS error while uploading the template.

**Error:-**

```
Invalid CORS request
```

deployment.yml:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: nifi
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.service: nifi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.service: nifi
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.service: nifi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nifi
          image: apache/nifi:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT
              value: '8080'b
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nifi
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.service: nifi
spec:
  ports:
    - name: '8080'
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.service: nifi
  type: ClusterIP
```

ingress.yml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-server-name: "on"
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
     - nifi.example.com
    secretName: nifi-tls-certs
  rules:
  - host: nifi.example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: nifi
              port:
                number: 8080
```

Tried `NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=nifi.example.com:443` too but no use.

Ingress log Error:-

```
2021/09/21 14:23:14 [warn] 1348#1348: *847786 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /tmp/client-body/0000000012, client: 43.225.23.99, server: nifi.example.com, request: "POST /nifi-api/process-groups/08bbe91d-017c-1000-dec3-0d02076b6539/templates/upload HTTP/2.0", host: "nifi.example.com", referrer: "https://nifi.example.com/nifi/"
```

Nifi log Error:-

```
2021-09-22 02:31:18,347 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-19] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor Reject: 'https://nifi.example.com' origin is not allowed
2021-09-22 02:31:18,350 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-19] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput write(array HeapByteBuffer@6ff9f1ff[p=0,l=20,c=20,r=20]={<<<Invalid CORS request>>>})
2021-09-22 02:31:18,350 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-19] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput write(array) s=OPEN,api=BLOCKING,sc=false,e=null aggregated !flush HeapByteBuffer@6ef19f58[p=0,l=20,c=32768,r=20]={<<<Invalid CORS request>>>ray","new...newClas}
2021-09-22 02:31:18,350 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-19] o.e.j.s.h.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor@3eb5c802 exclude by status 403
2021-09-22 02:31:18,350 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-19] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel sendResponse info=null content=HeapByteBuffer@6ef19f58[p=0,l=20,c=32768,r=20]={<<<Invalid CORS request>>>ray","new...newClas} complete=false committing=true callback=Blocker@1ef6baee{null}
2021-09-22 02:31:18,351 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-19] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel COMMIT for /nifi-api/process-groups/0b45181a-017c-1000-9ca3-332ebefb0500/templates/upload on HttpChannelOverHttp@5907776f{s=HttpChannelState@362f276b{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=COMMITTED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=13,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=//nifi.example.com/nifi-api/process-groups/0b45181a-017c-1000-9ca3-332ebefb0500/templates/upload,age=73}
Date: Wed, 22 Sep 2021 02:31:18 GMT
2021-09-22 02:31:18,351 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-19] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection generate: NEED_HEADER for SendCallback@43ebff93[PROCESSING][i=HTTP/1.1{s=403,h=8,cl=-1},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$SendCallback@27de40f2] (null,[p=0,l=20,c=32768,r=20],false)@START
```

Comment: I seem to remember something about wildcard `cors-allow-origin` and credentials...Try a domain list there?

Comment: Is this your entire deployment.yaml? You are missing `template` field.
Could you please include your entire yaml files? It would make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: @p10l Updated entire template and service as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix it with the below ingress annotation changes.

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;  
      proxy_set_header Origin http://nifi.example.com;
```

Ref: [Nginx config changes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6080)